# Call a method when class name not known at compile time

Tags: java, android

I have a number of sub-games, SubGame1, SubGame2 etc. Each is derived from a SubGame class and implements a static String getDescription() function.

I want to access these descriptions, e.g. SubGame1.getDescription(), SubGame2.getDescription() etc.

However I want to use a code loop and not all the subgames will exist.

How can I call getDescription() for a sub game when I only know the game number. Something like:

```
String description = Class.forName(this.getPackageName()+".SubGame"+subGameNo.getDescription();
```

but that returns:
    The method getDescription() is undefined for the type Class< capture#5-of ?>

Any ideas?

Comment: Is getDescription static? I don't think you can inherit from subgame any static method.

Comment: @Fire: He said it was static, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it, but you have to do it via the [`java.lang.reflect`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html) classes. `Class.forName` gives you a `Class` instance. You then call [`getMethod`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get the `Method`, on which you can then call [`invoke`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Off the top of my head:

```
Class cls;
Method getDescription;
String description;

cls = Class.forName(this.getPackageName() + ".SubGame" + subGameNo);
getDescription = cls.getMethod("getDescription");
description = getDescription.invoke(null);
```

...but you may have to play with the args a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Class.forName() to get the instance of the class.

Then you can call the method using reflection.  Code would look something like this

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(this.getPackageName()+".SubGame"+subGameNo);
Method descriptionMethod = clazz.getMethod("getDescription", new Class[] {});
String value = (String) descriptionMethod .invoke(this, new Object[] {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a Map of game numbers to game descriptions (`map.put(1, SubGame1.getDescription()`) and then just grab the description from the map as needed.  It's not as dynamic as you may want but it will work.